# filter Json messages from kafka consumer efficiently

Tags: java, json

I am reading log of Json objects from Kafka stream. Here is the format of each message:

```
{"class": "abc.cdf", "object":{....}}
```

I am interested in a particular "class" of messages which constitute only 10% of total messages received. How do I filter out the message based on this field efficiently without parsing the entire json for each new message?

Currently I am using ByteArraySerializer and ObjectMapper to parse to json pojo, then validate "class" field specifically. Sample code after for each batch of messages read from Kafka:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
for (record : records) {  
    MyRecord parsedRec = mapper.readValue(record, MyRecord.class);
    if (parsedRec == null || (!MYCLASSNAME.equals(parsedRec.getClass())))
       continue;
    ...
 }
```

Given the load of message stream, I want to spend minimal time filtering out uninterested messages.

Comment: I guess you can access the received byte array directly and check if your filter value as a sub array is present.

Comment: what do you mean is it slow? then try using multi threading, for me it seems you are on right track

Comment: Consider the "object" field containing many fields, don't you think it will be slow to parse each field unnecessarily? the latency will add up quickly. I am already multi threading across 10 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to parse only the `class` field and ignore the rest. So you use a new class `RecordClass` that contains only the `class` field and configure the mapper to don't fail on unknown properties (which is `object`).

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
RecordClass recordClass = mapper.readValue(record, RecordClass.class);
```

Then you parse the complete `MyRecord` only if `RecordClass` has the right class. Logically should be faster but in practice you need to test it.

Another approach is to send the messages with a specific class to another topic, so you basically filter on the producer side.